# Concatenate and split strings

Tags: c#, .net, string, escaping

Maybe this is a silly question. But I haven't found an answer yet.
I've got some strings. I would like to concatenate them and then split the resulting string in a different moment. I would like to know if there's something available inside the .NET Framework. The Join and Split methods of String work quite well. The problem is to escape the separator character.

For example, I would like to use the "@" as separator character. If I have "String1", "Str@ing2" and "String3", I would like to obtain "String1@Str@@ing2@String3".

Is there something that does what I need or do I have to write my own function?

Thank you.

Comment: Will you ever have an empty string that could cause two `@` right next to each other?

Comment: Should you be using a CSV library?

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I can avoid that situation. No CSV library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape the separator on the way in.

```
var inputs = ["String1", "Str@ing2", "String3"];
var joined = string.Join(inputs.Select(i => i.Replace("@", "@@"));
```

You can then split on single `@` chars.

```
var split = Regex.Split(joined, "(?<!@)@(?!@)");
```

This uses zero-width negative lookbehind/lookahead [patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to assert the character before and after the `@` is not another `@`. You should run some tests on cases where `@` is at the start or end of your input strings however.

Comment: @ufo - what do you want to happen when you split?

Comment: To split only when one "@" appears. Your last edit seems to answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: The Regex.Split does not work if one of the inputs is "@". How can I deal with this situation?

Comment: @ufo, firstly, do you think that as a human you can absolutely determine the correct separation of fields using your escaping technique. For example, what is the 'split' of string `@@@`? Is it four empty strings, one empty string and a `@` string, etc... you may need to devise a different scenario. Look at how existing escaping systems work, such as URL encoding.

Comment: you're right. This is the reason why I would prefer a framework solution. I suppose a proven solution is already been developed. Anyway, in my scenario an empty string is not admitted, so your example is not ever verified.

Answer (score 0):

Call `.Replace("@", "@@")` on each string before passing them to `.Join`